# Contextual newlines in tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, line-breaking, tocloft, shorttoc

I'm using a `shorttoc` with `tocloft` to put the names of chapters on a newline. Unfortunately, there are some chapters (such as the Preface or Index) which are not numbered, and I end up with additional, ugly, newlines between them:

[image: Shorttoc with ugly newlines]

Here is a MWE of my problem:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline} % This is the newline I'd like to be contextual
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{1}}


\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\shorttableofcontents{Contents}{0}

\addchap{Preface}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

\addchap{Postface}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

and the result is:

[image: MWE of the problem]

How could I keep the newlines for numbered chapters and get rid of it for entries that are not numbered?

**Edit:**

Actually, I'm realizing that what I'm trying to achieve is to *reduce the interline* between the chapter entries in the toc. How can I do that?

Comment: Personally, I think the ToC looks **better** with the extra spacing. IMHO, the only thing that needs changing is adding extra space above the index heading. Then all ‘normal’ chapters would be seen as one block, and ‘special’ chapters would be separate blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was the spacing between chapter entries in the toc.

This simple setting did the job:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-0.3em}
```

So I end up with something like:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{-0.3em}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter\ }
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newline}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
```

After adjusting the title, the result is:

[image: Fixed line skip]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `\newline` use your own macro, redefined by each chapter head to give a newline and then empty itself (hence to only produce one newline for each chapter head). When the `Chapter\` head is not used, the newline won't either.

```
\newcommand{\newlineornot}{}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter\ \gdef\newlineornot{\newline\gdef\newlineornot{}}}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newlineornot}
```

Or, in a full document,

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{shorttoc}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\newlineornot}{}
\renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter\ \gdef\newlineornot{\newline\gdef\newlineornot{}}}
\renewcommand\cftchapaftersnumb{\newlineornot}
\renewcommand\cftchapleader{\cftdotfill{1}}
\renewcommand\cftsecleader{\cftdotfill{1}}


\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\shorttableofcontents{Contents}{0}

\addchap{Preface}
\blindtext

\Blinddocument

\Blinddocument

\addchap{Postface}
\blindtext

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't fix my issue.

Comment: @Raphnik: ah, yes, actually I should have realized that the output still had the same spaces.